# SSH Permission denied from WSL

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While trying to SSH into a server (a university resource, I can read config files but not edit them) from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, I consistently get the same error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased).
```

And exit code 255. I am not prompted for a password.

I can connect to it from other computers when booted into linux proper, or on windows using a client such as PuTTY.
How do I fix this?

`ssh -vvvv` output:

```
> OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014  
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *  
> debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  
> debug1: Connecting to (hostname) [(host ip)] port 22.  
> debug1: Connection established.  
> debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier  
> debug3: Could not load "/home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_rsa type 1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
> debug1: identity file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8  
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8  
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000  
> debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "remote-und.ida.liu.se" from file "/home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts"  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys  
> debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com  
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0   
> debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0   
> debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com  
> debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none  
> debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com  
> debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none  
> debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT  
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY  
> debug1: Server host key: RSA 43:02:bf:af:fc:fb:88:52:bf:cd:b5:d1:25:fc:bf:66  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "(hostname)" from file "/home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts"  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "(host ip)" from file "/home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts"  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts:3  
> debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys  
> debug1: Host '(hostname)' is known and matches the RSA host key.  
> debug1: Found key in /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/known_hosts:1  
> debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct  
> debug2: kex_derive_keys  
> debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
> debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent  
> debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth  
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
> debug2: key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fffc1a8fc00),  
> debug2: key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),  
> debug2: key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),  
> debug2: key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),  
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased  
> debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased  
> debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive  
> debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex  
> debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive  
> debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex  
> debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex  
> debug1: No valid Key exchange context  
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
> debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic  
> debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive  
> debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic  
> debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic  
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
> No Kerberos credentials available  
>   
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
> No Kerberos credentials available  
>   
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
>   
>   
> debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  
> No Kerberos credentials available  
>   
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
> debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey  
> debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive  
> debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey  
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_rsa  
> debug3: send_pubkey_test  
> debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply  
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased  
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_dsa  
> debug3: no such identity: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory  
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ecdsa  
> debug3: no such identity: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory  
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ed25519  
> debug3: no such identity: /home/Pjoelj/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory  
> debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method  
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.  
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased).
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you're actually inserting a password because PowerShell has a different method to paste text - by right click (not by Ctrl+v or Shift+Ins).